# Android Reportbug get Error/Exception

Tags: android, email, report, beta

I'm releasing a beta-version of my app for friends. So that they can test it. I implemented an email function for them to report bugs. But to know specific what triggered the error/exception I want to add the logcat to the email. How can I do that?

Comment: there are various ways but the best way is to use ACRA.

Comment: For crash reporting, you can ise tools like *Crashlytics* or *Rollbar* which provides logcat along with crash.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use https://fabric.io/. It 's quite good, you can see bugs/exception even when you use proguard( still can see your bugs)